# Mysql - Sum count result of join query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have users, who can have many bookings during a time period. Each booking can have multiple people.

The query could look like:

```
SELECT users.*, 
(SELECT COUNT(person) FROM person_to_booking WHERE person_to_booking.booking = bookings.id) AS people_per_booking
FROM users
LEFT JOIN bookings ON users.id = bookings.user
GROUP BY users.id
```

This returns one result, with the last bookings number of people. If I remove the `GROUP BY` then I get 4 rows, each with the correct number of people for that booking.

I need to have one row, with a `SUM()` of the `COUNT(person)`. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

Tables are structured like so:

```
Users

id | name 
---------
1  | Dave
2  | Bob

Bookings

id | user | company
-------------
1  | 1    | Big Group
2  | 1    | Big Group
3  | 2    | Small Company

Person to Bookings

id | person | bookings
----------------------
1  | 1      | 1
1  | 2      | 1
1  | 3      | 1
1  | 4      | 1
1  | 5      | 2
1  | 6      | 2
```

So a user can have bookings against them, and then a booking can have many persons.

Comment: Tables structure may help for answering.. thanks.

Comment: @roetnig added a sample structure.

Comment: What is your question?  That is, what results do you want to calculate from the data?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need a sum of the results from the subquery for each row.

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand you correctly

```
SELECT users.*,
SELECT SUM(cper) FROM (SELECT COUNT(person) as cper FROM person_to_booking WHERE person_to_booking.booking = bookings.id) AS people_per_booking
FROM users
LEFT JOIN bookings ON users.id = bookings.user
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: Unkown column cper in field list?